# How to subscribe to "route" event using sammy.js?

Tags: events, navigation, sammy.js

I use sammy.js for navigating and I have to handle an event which happens after changing a link. For example, a user clicks on "#/contact" link so, after successful navigation I want my event to be triggered. I've found "after" property and tried to insert this code:

```
this.after('#/contact', function () {
    //my code
});
```

but it's not executing.
What am I doing wrong?

In fact, the problem has come from the following situation:

I have a page with 2 tabs: Home and Contact. Contact contains google map.

If a user, first, goes to Contact, google map is loaded properly but if a user comes to Home tab and then switch to Contact tab, google map is not loaded properly, I can see only a small piece of map in the top left corner.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using custom events to handle this:

```
var app = $.sammy(function() {

    this.get('#/contact', function() {
        this.trigger('myEvent', { myData: 'This a contact!' });
    });

});
```

Or if you want to listen to all routes that have been run, try:

```
this.bind('run-route', function() {
    console.log("I got routed");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I call 'myEvent', the actual 'contact' view is not loaded. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: So you are trying to change the route rather than raise an event when a route change is made?

Comment: I need to raise an event and then I expect that this page will be loaded as usual

Comment: So you want to manually run the #contact route? Try app.setLocation('#/contact');

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you just need to do this:

`location.hash = "contact";`

And the route event will fire.